# How to Re-Tag questions since latest update?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can one re-tag other questions? Either I can't find the button or the functionality was changed since the last update of ROS answers. It used to be possible with enough Karma.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29691/how-to-re-tag-questions-since-latest-update?/) by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5904 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2012-03-14**:
Could you please test this now? Thank you.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-14**:
Yes, seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The retag link is in the same row of icons as "edit", "close", etc. that are below the poster's name and information block. It is between the "edit" and "flag offensive" icons - at least that's where it is for me when viewing this question.

Can you retag your own question? If it's just not showing up on other people's questions and it used to, perhaps the required karma amount changed in the update.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-14**:
Yes, I see them for my own question and it works, but not for others. http://answers.ros.org/faq/ still mentions 100 Karma for re-tags and I should even be able to edit. The thing is that there is not any button under someone else's question for me, not even "flag offensive".